# How to add username in URL (i.e. URL Rewriting)?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to user's username in the url after successful signup/login, like this

```
http://myweb.com/username/255
http://myweb.com/username/settings
```

I am using ASP.Net Rewrite module and this is one of the re-write rule I am currently using which generate `http://myweb.com/home/255`:

```
<rule name="HomeRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^home$"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/home.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

I tried to change myself something like this:

```
<rule name="HomeRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^{R:1}/home$"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/home.aspx"/>
</rule>
```

but it's not working and I know I am doing wrong. So any help in this regard?

Comment: Why not use page routing? I have some page routing code that add the username into route data. Or is it that you want the URL in the browser's address bar to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)** is part of MVC you can use the mechanism in ASP.Net Forms Applications as well (see https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx)

E.g. at Global.asax's void `Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)`
you can add this code

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("Users", new Route("{username}/settings", 
new CustomRouteHandler()));
```

where the Custom class `CustomRouteHandler` implements `IRouteHandler` sending the request to your settings code (view).

You only need to actually redirect the user to that url as soon as he's authenticated (and keep him there) That could be done e.g. in Global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)`